# How to change the line thickness of whiskers using stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to change the line thickness of the whiskers when using `stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")`:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(cond = factor( rep(c("A","B"), each=500) ), 
  value = c(rnorm(500,mean=1,sd=0.2),rnorm(500, mean=1.5,sd=0.1)))
ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(lwd=0.2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y=value)) + 
      stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", 
       stat_params = list(width = 0.5,size = 5.0)) + 
      geom_boxplot(lwd=0.2)
```

In the second plot `lwd=0.2` changes the thickness of the lines in the box, but the whiskers remain the same.

[image]  [image]

### Update

Thanks @eipi10,

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y=value)) + stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar",
    width = 0.5, size=0.2) + geom_boxplot(lwd=0.2)
```

your solution changes the thickness of the lines of the whiskers but it makes the horizontal line at their end as wide as the box, instead of half (width = 0.5).

But using

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y=value)) + stat_boxplot(geom ="errorbar",
    stat_params = list(width = 0.5), size=0.2) + geom_boxplot(lwd=0.2)
```

or

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y=value)) + stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar",
    stat_params = list(width = 0.5, size=0.2)) + geom_boxplot(lwd=0.2)
```

then the whiskers width is half of the box as intended but their line thickness is the default one that is thicker than the lines of the box.

In other words, I cannot simultaneously change the thickness of the lines and the width of the whiskers.

### Update two

I am getting the same result with these two pieces of code (both without stat_params)

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y=value)) + stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar",
    width=0.5, size=5) + geom_boxplot(lwd=0.2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y=value)) + stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar",
    width=0.2, size=5) + geom_boxplot(lwd=0.2)
```

[image]  [image]

Jose

Comment: If you want the end of the whisker to be thinner, you can reduce the value of `width` in my original code (e.g., `width=0.3` or whatever value works for you).

Comment: Thanks again @eipi10, but it doesn't work for me. I can change the thickness of the lines but the width of the whisker is not altered by the 'widht' parameter. I am using Rstudio in OS X Yosemite with  R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) and ggplot2 1.0.1.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by the "width of the whisker". See my updated answer.

Comment: By 'width of the whisker' I mean the width of the horizontal line at the end of the whisker. In my case stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar",
    width = 0.5, size=5) or stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar",
    width = 0.2, size=5) give me the same result: the horizontal line at the end of the whiskers in both cases is as wide as the box. I don't understand why. Thanks, Jose.

Comment: If you're still using `stat_params`, then that's the reason it's not working. Use the code in my answer, rather than `stat_params`.

Comment: Is it possible to have the horizontal but not the vertical line of the error bars displayed?

Answer (score 11):

If I understand your question, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y=value)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width=0.5, size=5) +
  geom_boxplot(lwd=0.2)
```

Here's the result with two different `width` settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=cond, y=value)) + stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", 
stat_params = list(width = 0.5), geom_params = list(size = 2))
+geom_boxplot(size = 2)
```